# Management API: batch request > Behavior when one of the nested HTTP request fails

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm batching GA Management API calls (insert Web Property User Links) as described on this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/batching

Using Pything Client Library:

```
link = service.management().webpropertyUserLinks().insert(accountId, webPropertyId, body)
batch.add(link)

batch.execute(http=http)
```

Did I understand correctly, if any of the nested HTTP request fails, all pending HTTP requests in the batch will fail to execute as well? This seems to be the behavior I'm experiencing.

I had expected rest of the calls will still be executed!

Thanks a lot for any clarification

Answer (score 0):

This is how batching works unfortunately it is assumed that the calls are linked and if on fails they should all fail.

Answer:    yes if one of the requests within your batching request fails they will all fail.